# Unable to get the value of the selected <select> element

Tags: javascript, html

Here is a drop-down list  and you need to determine which element  is selected but an error occurs. Please help to understand.

```
app.js:350 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined
    at onChangeSelectCategory (app.js:350)
    at HTMLSelectElement.onchange
```

with HTML:

```
<body>
<p align="center"><label>Category</label></p>
<p align="center">
<select onchange="onChangeSelectCategory()" style="visibility: visible" id="adCategory" class="category" name="category" style="width: 300pt">
    <option value="1">Category 1</option>
    <option value="2">Category 2</option>
    <option value="3">Category 3</option>
    <option value="4">Category 4</option>
</select></p>

<p align="center"><label>Sub Category</label></p>
<p align="center">
<select style="visibility: visible" id="subCategory" class="category" name="subcategory" style="width: 300pt">

</select></p>
<script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
</body>
```

and JS:

```
var adCategoryRef = document.getElementById('adCategory');
var subCategoryRef = document.getElementById('subCategory');
function  onChangeSelectCategory() {
    var adSelectedCategoryVal = adCategoryRef.options[adCategoryRef.selectedIndex].text; //error
    switch (adSelectedCategoryVal) {
        case 'Category 1': {
```

Comment: Please read through [how to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask) and update your post with better information: you're showing two selects, which one is the problem? you're showing an error with a line number, but a fragment of JS code without saying which line numbers those represent, etc. But on a modern HTML+JS note: don't use `style` and `onchange` attributes. Your styles come from CSS classes, and your event handling should be set up in JS (using addEventListener code), not using the legacy HTML4 "let's just stick JS code in HTML attribute markup, what could go wrong" approach =)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans This is due to code formatting, but if you scroll the JS code to the right, you'll see which line causes the error, there is a comment

Comment: I put your code in a [codepen](https://codepen.io/Rohittt/pen/ExgzMNm) and it works perfectly fine.

Comment: No, as someone asking for help, it's really on you to fix that formatting: make it legible =) (also, if Rojo's correct then you also forgot to verify that the code you're showing is actually a [MCVE] for the problem, so that's something important that you should never forget to check)

Comment: Where is your script loaded in the page (if it's loaded before you define the select is rendered your `adCategoryRef` will be undefined. You could move the script to the bottom of the page or put the `var adCategoryRef = document.getElementById('adCategory');` into the `onChangeSelectCategory` function

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans - such a nice man who explains everything in detail instead just closing the question like most people do here. Respect

Comment: It is an interesting question though

Comment: The code looks fine, I have tested it myself, there doesn't seem to be a problem (tested in Chrome and Safari). I am 100% sure, you have the error in exactly the part of the code, which you didn't posted ;=)

Answer (score 0):

As Tom mentioned in his comment, adCategoryRef might be not rendered. I just recommend you to try passing the select element in function parameters, like:

```
function onChangeSelectCategory(adCategoryRefSel) {
    var adSelectedCategoryVal = adCategoryRefSel.options[adCategoryRefSel.selectedIndex].text; //error
}
```

And html:

```
<select onChange="onChangeSelectCategory(this);" style="visibility: visible" id="adCategory" class="category" name="category" style="width: 300pt">
```

Comment: I think you are right, it might be a timing problem.

Comment: yes probably it's. Because there is no other reason for error.

Answer (score 0):

Here I changed but there is already another error with another .

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined
    at onChangeSelectCategory (app.js:352)
    at HTMLSelectElement.onchange
```

JS

```
var subCategoryRef = document.getElementById('subCategory');
function  onChangeSelectCategory(adCategoryRefSel) {
    var adSelectedCategoryVal = adCategoryRefSel.options[adCategoryRefSel.selectedIndex].text;
    switch (adSelectedCategoryVal) {
        case 'Category 1': {
            var length = subCategoryRef.options.length; \\ error
            for (i = length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
                subCategoryRef.options[i] = null;
            }
```

HTML

```
<body>
<p align="center"><label>Category</label></p>
<p align="center"><select onChange="onChangeSelectCategory(this);" style="visibility: visible" id="adCategory" class="category" name="category" style="width: 300pt">
    <option value="1">Category 1</option>
    <option value="2">Category 2</option>
    <option value="3">Category 3</option>
    <option value="4">Category 4</option>
</select></p>

<p align="center"><label>Sub Category</label></p>
<p align="center"><select style="visibility: visible" id="subCategory" class="category" name="subcategory" style="width: 300pt">

</select></p>
<script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: var subCategoryRef = document.getElementById('subCategory'); navigate it into -> function  onChangeSelectCategory(adCategoryRefSel)  . let's see if it does something good.

Comment: You probably have a timing issue. Check out this post, how to generally overcome those issues. The Idea is, use jQuery or similar libraries to make sure, your DOM is loaded and ready to be used in JS functions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588040/window-onload-vs-document-onload